# 'question_text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to follow the Polls tutorial I include both the `urls.py`, from the project and the `models.py` from the polls directory.

```
q = Question(question_text="some text", pub_date=timezone.now))
```

results in the following error:

```
'question_text' is  an invalid keyword argument for this function.
```

**mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**polls/models.py**

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your models here.

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in django shell, you first need to import the models you are working with, in your case you need to import model *Question*

let's recall everything from beginning.

**Step 1: Activate your shell**

```
python manage.py shell
```

**Step 2: Import your model *Question* and also import *timezone***

```
from polls.models import Question
from django.utils import timezone
```

**Step 3: Now run your query**

```
q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now())
```

If you have noticed, here is what you were doing wrong,according to your question.

**Step 4: Run save method**

```
q.save()
```

All of this is w.r.t [Polls Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api) Playing with api.

Answer (score 0):

I think while learning tutorial you have done lot of code changes and those are not reflected in sql database.

SO, before doing above your steps follow the bellow steps.

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations polls
python manage.py migrate
```

and now do this

```
python manage.py shell 
from polls.models import Question 
from django.utils import timezone 
q = Question(question_text="What's new?", pub_date=timezone.now() 
q.save()
```